CountryData syntax
Which of the following syntax variations are correct? For the incorrect? syntax, what does the obtained value represent? Statements 2/3 and 4/5 are identical; I was trying to see if it was a bug.


CountryData["Ireland", "GiniIndex"]
CountryData[#, "GiniIndex"] &@Entity["Country", "Ireland"]
CountryData[Entity["Country", "Ireland"], "GiniIndex"]
#["GiniIndex"] &@Entity["Country", "Ireland"]
Entity["Country", "Ireland"][EntityProperty["Country", "GiniIndex"]]


Thanks for your help.

Maybe the two forms just read data from different sources.

I was trying to do GeoRegionValuePlot with selected properties for various world countries and realized that the colors didn't match, so I reduced it to a MWE.

'EntityProperty' probably reads data from Wolfram alpha which is updated more frequently. And CountryData probably reads data from some database that was created  when your Mathematica version was released, so it means the data is older.

See diagram on https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ireland+gini+index

It looks like CountryData doesn't return the latest data but from a few years ago, so you should use Entity. You can reconsiliate the results by explicitly providing the year.
CountryData["Ireland", "GiniIndex"]
(* 0.306 *)
    
CountryData["Ireland", "GiniIndex", "Date"]
(* 2018 *)

Entity["Country", "Ireland"]["GiniIndex"]
(* 0.292 *)
    
Entity["Country", "Ireland"]["GiniIndex", "Date" -> 2018]
Entity["Country", "Ireland"][Dated["GiniIndex", 2018]]
(* 0.306 *)

Entity["Country", "Ireland"]["GiniIndex", "Date" -> All]
(* TemporalData[TimeSeries, {...}]] *)

CountryData["Ireland", {"GiniIndex", 2024}]
(* This should work, but it doesn't ... *)

